# Reading a JSON-file with jQuery fails in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: javascript, json, html

I'm very new in developing apps for Win8 RT with html5 and JavaScript. I want to read data from a JSON-file and here's the problem:

```
function test() {
var _url = 'js\test.json';
$.getJSON(_url, function (data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var tweet = data[i].info.Name;
        document.writeln(tweet);
        //$(".test").append(tweet + 'hgjhjh');                
    }
})
};
test();
```

And this is my JSON-file:

```
{
"info": ["Name": "Max", Adress": "Fakestreet", "City": "New York"]
}
```

My code stops at this line and I got no exception by the system:

```
$.getJSON(_url, function (data) {
```

I included the jQuery functions in a .js-file and also called it by

```
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

in my default.html.

I've searched a lot but found no solution for this specific problem. Not even the documentation of jQuery.com helped me.

Did I make any mistakes by including jQuery into my project? Or do you have any further ideas what could be the problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is your code copy-paste from the actual code? Because if so, there's a typo - you're missing an opening quote before Adress.

Comment: Your JSON isn't valid, you are trying to use keys inside an Array (which is not possible in JS as there are no associative Arrays). Use `{}` for object literal notation and `[]` for Arrays.

Comment: It is not related to Visual Studio 2012

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON is not valid. You are trying to use keys inside Arrays, which is not possible in JS as there are no associcative Arrays (but Objects). Use object literal notation instead:

```
{
"info": {"Name": "Max", "Adress": "Fakestreet", "City": "New York"}
}
```

Also note that you were missing a double quote delimiting the `Adress` key.

Now you could lookup data inside your AJAX success callback like:

```
$.each(data, function(){
   console.log(this.Name);
   console.log(this.Adress);
   console.log(this.City);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a quote.

```
{
"info": ["Name": "Max", Adress": "Fakestreet", "City": "New York"]
}
```

should be

```
{
"info": ["Name": "Max", "Adress": "Fakestreet", "City": "New York"]
}
```

Firebug would catch something like that.

Comment: That's not a valid data structure, you cannot use keys in Arrays. Either make it an object or wrap the Array's NV pairs inside objects.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing quote and instead of bracket "[" there should be curly brace "{".
You can check validity of json here   http://jsonlint.com/

```
 {
    "info": {
              "Name": "Max",
              "Adress": "Fakestreet",
              "City": "New York"
            }
}
```